# jackson xml text using jackson custom serializer

Tags: json, xml, serialization, jackson

I am trying to implement a custom jackson xml serializer for a polymorphic object. 
In the code below, " who?" is a StringElement class for which I don't want the field name, just the value. But the code gives the following error-

```
@Override
public void serialize(Template template, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,  SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
    throws IOException {
    // expected output - "<template><star><star/> who?</template>"

    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    for (AimlElement element : template.getTemplates()) {
        if (element instanceof Star) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("star", "");
        } else if (element instanceof StringElement) {
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(new String(element.getValue()));
        }
    }
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
}
```

Error -

JsonGenerationException: Can not write raw value, expecting field name

Comment: Provide an example of the XML output you expect. It's difficult to figure out what you're getting at.

Comment: heyy robby, i've added the serialized xml in the comment

Comment: Update your question.